# how make perfect reload or reset function in memory game card?

Tags: javascript

i try make reset button to my game

i try make function called startGame to reload the cards and reload button and it should back all the card to the default case and clear all added classes but this don't happen

html Code

```
<body>
    <div class="features">
        <header>
            <h1>Memory Game</h1>
        </header>
        <ul class="stars">
            <li id ="starOne"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
            <li id="starTwo"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
            <li id="starThree"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="moves">
            <p><b><span id ="steps">00</span> Moves</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="timer">
            <p><b>Time <span id="minutes">00</span> M : <span id="seconds">00</span> S</b></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="restart"><i class="fas fa-redo-alt"></i>   Reset</button>
        <button class="info"><i class="fas fa-info"></i>  Info</button>
    </div>
    <div id="memory_Game">
        <div id="game_structure"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="restart" onclick="startGame()">
        <p><b>Reset</b></p> <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
    </div> -->
    <!-- congratulation message -->
    <div id="winner" class="win-modal">
        <div class="win-content">
            <h1>Congratulations! You win!</h1>
            <div class="win-msg">
                <h2>You've earned <span id="starScore"></span>!</h2>
          You won the game in time <span id="playTime"></span>  using <span id="trails"></span> moves.</div>
          <button id="playAgain" class="button">Play again</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Card.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var images = ["fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting", "fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting", "fas fa-cut", "fas fa-cut", "fas fa-bicycle", "fas fa-bicycle", "fas fa-asterisk", "fas fa-asterisk", "fas fa-atom", "fas fa-atom", "fas fa-car-crash", "fas fa-car-crash", "fas fa-chess", "fas fa-chess", "fas fa-drum", "fas fa-drum"];

var oppened_card = [];
var matched_card = [];
var matchedCardContainer = [];
var moves = 0;
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");

window.onload = startGame();
const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart');
console.log(restartButton);
restartButton.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function Shuffle(array) {
  var i = array.length,
    tempValue, randomindex;
  while (--i > 0) {
    randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    tempValue = array[randomindex];
    array[randomindex] = array[i];
    array[i] = tempValue;
  }
  return array;
}

function startGame() {
  images = Shuffle(images);

  const game_structure = document.getElementById('game_structure');

  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var card = document.createElement("section");
    var front = document.createElement("div");
    var back = document.createElement("div");
    front.classList.add("front");
    back.classList.add("back");
    card.classList.remove('stopPointer', 'cardAnimate', 'hidden');
    front.classList.remove('front_ro');
    back.classList.remove('back_ro', "open");
    card.appendChild(front);
    card.appendChild(back);
    back.innerHTML = `<i class="${images[i]}"></i>`;
    fragment.appendChild(card);
    // debugger; 
  }
  game_structure.appendChild(fragment);
  reset();
  game_structure.addEventListener('click', element_Listener);
}

function element_Listener(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'SECTION') {
    startTimer();
    if (oppened_card.length < 2) {
      flip_Card(event);
    }
  }
}

function flip_Card(event) {
  event.target.childNodes[0].classList.add('front_ro');
  event.target.childNodes[1].classList.add('back_ro', "open");
  event.target.classList.add('stopPointer');
  if (oppened_card.length == 0) {
    oppened_card.push(event.target.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
    matched_card.push(event.target);

  } else if (oppened_card.length == 1) {
    oppened_card.push(event.target.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
    matched_card.push(event.target);
    moveCounter();
    matched_card[0].classList.add('cardAnimate');
    matched_card[1].classList.add('cardAnimate');

    if (oppened_card[0] == oppened_card[1]) {
      matchedCardContainer.push(matched_card[0], matched_card[1]);
      console.log(matchedCardContainer);
      match();
      game_over();
      // if (checked_classes.includes(false) == false){
      //     var lastMoves =`${document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML} Moves`;
      //     var lastTime = `Time= ${document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML}M:${document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML}S`;
      //     stopTimer();      
      // }
    } else {
      unmatch();
    }
  }
}

function moveCounter() {
  moves++;
  document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML = moves;
}

function match() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    matched_card[0].classList.add('hidden');
    matched_card[1].classList.add('hidden');
    oppened_card = [];
    matched_card = [];
  }, 1000);
}

function unmatch() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    matched_card[0].childNodes[0].classList.remove('front_ro');
    matched_card[0].childNodes[1].classList.remove('back_ro');
    matched_card[0].classList.remove('cardAnimate', 'stopPointer');
    matched_card[1].childNodes[0].classList.remove('front_ro');
    matched_card[1].childNodes[1].classList.remove('back_ro');
    matched_card[1].classList.remove('cardAnimate', 'stopPointer');
    oppened_card = [];
    matched_card = [];
  }, 1000);
}

let timerRunning = false;
var gameTime;

function startTimer() {
  if (!timerRunning) {
    timerRunning = true;

    var totalSeconds = 0;
    gameTime = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
  }

  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  }

  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
}

function stopTimer() {
  if (timerRunning) {
    timerRunning = false;
    clearInterval(gameTime);
  }
}
// var checked_classes =[];
function game_over() {
  // var hidden_cards = document.getElementsByTagName('section');
  // // console.log(hidden_cards);
  // for (let hidden_card of hidden_cards){
  // //    console.log(hidden_card);
  //    let checked_class = hidden_card.classList.contains("hidden");
  //    checked_classes.push(checked_class);
  // //    console.log(checked_classes);

  // }
  if (matchedCardContainer.length == images.length) {
    var lastMoves = `${document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML} Moves`;
    var lastTime = `Time= ${document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML}M:${document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML}S`;
    stopTimer();

  }
}

function reset() {
  moves = 0;
  document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML = moves;
  document.getElementsByClassName('stars')[0].style.visibility = "visible";
  totalSeconds = 0;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = 0;
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = 0;
  clearInterval(gameTime);
}
```

expected result to reset the game and start again 
the actual results no thing happen and even don't activate any error

Comment: One quick observation  `var totalSeconds = 0;` shouldn't be in a function, it should be at the top of your code.

Comment: Can you add the remaining code? For instance, I don't see an element with class `.restart` in your code.